# Problema al añadir imagenes a botones en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy tratando de añadir imágenes a mis botones en C# pero por algún motivo no me las toma. Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

Selecciono un botón y en las propiedades elijo el `BackgroundImage`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se abre la ventana de diálogo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Importo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, cuando doy aceptar es como sino tomara la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `BackgroundImage` me sigue diciendo **ninguno**. Ya probé limpiando/compilando/recompilando, cerrando y volviendo a abrir el proyecto pero no ha dado resultado. ¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

Este es el código del diseñador:

```
        this.btnEfectivo.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
        this.btnEfectivo.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        this.btnEfectivo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, 263);
        this.btnEfectivo.Name = "btnEfectivo";
        this.btnEfectivo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 106);
        this.btnEfectivo.TabIndex = 4;
        this.btnEfectivo.Text = "IMPRIMIR EFECTIVO (SIN CRÉDITO)";
        this.btnEfectivo.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        this.btnEfectivo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

He conseguido mostrar la imagen añadiendo lo siguiente al código del diseñador:

```
this.btnEfectivo.BackgroundImage = global::ProvidusApp.Properties.Resources.auto91;
```

El problema con eso es que a la hora de ver el diseño sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, al momento de depurar la solución funciona sin problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la **propiedad Image**, en vez de **BackgroundImage**, y una vez que esté puesta podrías modificar la propiedad **ImageAlign** para que la muestre en la dirección que deseas.

Comment: Eso hice, pero no está alineandolo en ningún lado. Lo deja en la misma posición :/

Comment: Como quieres que se alinee

Comment: Pues, lo mejor sería en TopCenter

Comment: Para obtener ese resultado alomejor debes combinar varias propiedades, como imagealign, textalign, textimagerelation

Comment: Mira ver sino hablamos por el chat